# Two the same declarations

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

In phpStorm when I want to go to declaration (ctrl+left mouse button - javascript function) I always have two the same declarations to choose from. Both are identical.

Comment: Please try "File | Invalidate caches" and restart if you have not tried it yet.

Comment: are you working with AngularJS? Please see [WEB-14499](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14499) - does it look similar?

Comment: Yes - Angular JS - thanks for clue